# Trying to install Mate but libgtk-3-0 wants ubuntu4 and I have ubuntu4.1

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, mate

I tried:

```
echo "libgtk-3-0 hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

I got the answer from this thread:
[libgtk-3-0 dependency issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235377/libgtk-3-0-dependency-issues)
It didn't help. Do I need to install an older version?

This the response when I try to:

```
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgail-3-0 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.24.25-1ubuntu4.1) but 3.24.25-1ubuntu4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am using Ubuntu 21.04 Linux 5.11.0-17-generic on x86_64

Output from "`apt policy libgail-3-0`" is: `The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime. Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) and [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/)

Comment: You haven't provided release details so we cannot answer fully. If you're using *focal* then ubuntu4 is the latest, if using *groovy* then ubuntu41 is available in -updates; so you need to add that to your sources (or check sources as it should be there..)   We need release details for specific answers, which you didn't provide, so do searches yourself as you know the release and can come up with a specific cause (I won't cover other releases, you can look yourself; packages.ubuntu.com or CLI tools).

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Along with answers to the other questions, the output of `apt policy libgail-3-0` would be informative.

Comment: That is not a valid output for an `apt policy` command. Java is irrelevant.

Comment: I must have entered it wrong previously the output from "apt policy libgail-3-0" is libgail-3-0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.24.25-1ubuntu4.1
  Version table:
     3.24.25-1ubuntu4.1 500 (phased 80%)
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 Packages
     3.24.25-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages